# what general physical arguments discredit induced emission of nuclei?

Tags: nuclear-physics, laser

trying to read a bit about "quantum nucleonics", i've encountered [this rebuttal from people at Livermore](http://www.eurekalert.org/pub_releases/2001-08/llnl-pcr081301.php) that induced radiation stimulation of Hafnium nuclei is possible. Something that catches my eye is the phrase "The earlier reports were also very unlikely, in any case, on very general physics arguments".

**Question:** what 'very general physics arguments' may have referred the author?

Answer (score 2):

This is just the separation in energy scales of the X-ray and $\gamma$-ray emissions. For the nucleus, an x-ray is essentially a slowly varying static electromagnetic field, the wavelength is much longer than the object, and the static electromagnetic field doesn't affect the decay process by any appreciable amount.